# Why do dig, nslookup, and host cause named to have errors?

Tags: networking, dns

I installed bind 9.11.0-P3 on a Macbook Pro today, along with the latest hints file.  It launches during boot and does not exit.  However, it does not seem to be caching, and it logs lots of errors.

Years ago, I had version 7 or 8 running.  The caching improved performance only slightly, but it could be verified by timing host, nslookup, or dig.  First try for a not-recently-used address would take more than a second.  Subsequent tries would be a few milliseconds.

Now, **all** lookups take one to three seconds, and the log is surprising.

First, it complains of format errors for **all** thirteen root servers on IPv4:

```
25-Feb-2017 11:50:51.661 DNS format error from 192.36.148.17#53 resolving ./NS: non-improving referral
25-Feb-2017 11:50:51.661 FORMERR resolving './NS/IN': 192.36.148.17#53
```

Then, **all** are unreachable on IPv6:

```
25-Feb-2017 11:50:51.644 host unreachable resolving 'burgosnorte.org/A/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
```

and often (but not always) one or more of them is "lame":

```
25-Feb-2017 11:53:31.944 lame server resolving 'earthlink.net' (in '.'?): 198.97.190.53#53
```

With or without the "lame server," I get an answer which reverse DNS (with the same errors) shows is correct.

In my previous "years ago" installation, I never checked for those errors because I could tell by timing that it worked.  The localhost.zone and named.local that the installer created are identical to those I built by hand way back when.

Caching **does** appear to work for reverse DNS: took only 21 ms. the second try, and logged no errors.

Comment: Do you use forwarders with named or is it in full-recursive mode? And do you know if your ISP tends to intercept DNS requests?

Comment: The "ISP" is a very poor WiFi connection at a public library.  I use it because it's free and the one I pay for is just as bad.  I don't know why my edit on this question has been reversed.  I got it to run, but not well.  I am pretty sure it is fully recursive.  I went to SuperUser to discuss that.  Posted the link here, and SAW it appear in comments, but now it's gone!

Comment: SE is weird today—I just answered that five minutes ago and was told that the comment was entered successfully!

Comment: And five seconds after that complaint was added, the previous one appeared.  Also, ignore the bit about SuperUser.  I thought I was commenting on http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/274380/65467